# ASP EF7 Set column value in migration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I want to move from autoincrement ids to composite primary keys. So, these two entities

```c#
public class SeasonTeam
{
    public int SeasonTeamId { get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }   
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}


public class GroupEntry
{
    public int GroupEntryId { get; set; }
    public int SeasonTeamId { get; set; }

    public SeasonTeam SeasonTeam { get; set; }
}
```

will now look like this

```c#
public class SeasonTeam
{
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }   
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}


public class GroupEntry
{
    public int GroupEntryId { get; set; }
    public int SeasonId { get; set; }   
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public SeasonTeam SeasonTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Visual Studio generated migration code, but it corrupts data.

```c#
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "SeasonId",
    table: "GroupEntry",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0);

migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "TeamId",
    table: "GroupEntry",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0);



migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_GroupEntry_SeasonTeam_SeasonTeamId", table: "GroupEntry");
migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(name: "PK_SeasonTeam", table: "SeasonTeam");
migrationBuilder.DropColumn(name: "SeasonTeamId", table: "SeasonTeam");
```

Default value 0 obviously won't work, I need ids from referenced SeasonTeam table, but I didn't find any examples. How can I set proper id values for a new composite key before I delete old primary key column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this programmatically with EF's APIs, however, if you can write the SQL to move the values from one table to another, you can add a custom migration step after the Add column operations and before the drop column operations.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"INSERT INTO ...(your SQL here)");
```

From the limited info in your question, I can't tell you what that SQL should be.

Comment: this seems like a way to go. do you know what purpose has parameter defaultValueSql in AddColumn call?

Comment: example: `CREATE TABLE t (Modified DateTime2 DEFAULT GETDATE()).` You would set defaultValueSql = "GETDATE()".